# Python File Reading into another text in diff format

Tags: python, text-processing

my text file look like
name1\n
name2\n
name3\n

I want read this file and store in another text file like this('name1','name2','name3') in Python, Could you please help anyone.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

```
YourTextFile = 'name1\n name2\n name3\n'
ListOFNames = YourTextFile.split('\n ')
AllNamesList = [x.replace('\n', '') for x in ListOFNames]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: I meant \n means new line.list contains one by one